# Mapping of the unit circle to a wedge shaped region

Tags: complex-analysis

We want to show that the mapping $w=\left(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^\frac23$ maps the unit circle on to a wedge-shaped region and illustrate graphically ....My problem here is that plugging $z=e^{i\theta}$ and simplifying does not yield anything I can work with...

Comment: Treating your function as a composition of $z^\frac23$ and $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ should help. (Those mappings should already be familiar if you're doing this sort of problem.)

Comment: It's not the unit circle. It's the unit disc.